# Unable to combine plugins DSL with the buildscript block

Tags: spring, gradle, spring-boot, gradle-plugin

I am fairly new to both Spring Boot and Gradle. In trying to simplify my build.gradle script, I came across the following problem. Since I'm using Gradle 2.5, I decided to take advantage of Gradle's new plugins DSL. Unfortunately, one of the plugins that I needed to use, the `spring-boot-gradle-plugin`, was not included on the Gradle plugins portal. To work around that, I used the old `buildscript {...}`, `apply plugin:` syntax for that plugin and specified the rest of my plugins in the new `plugins {...}` syntax. The result was the following build script:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath: "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.3.2.RELEASE"
    }
}

plugins {
    id "io.spring.dependency-management" version "0.5.4.RELEASE"
    id "java"
    id "idea"
}

apply plugin: 'spring-boot'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom 'com.vaadin:vaadin-bom:7.6.1'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")
    compile("com.vaadin:vaadin-spring-boot-starter")
    compile("com.h2database:h2")
    testCompile("junit:junit")
}

jar {
    baseName = 'my-spring-boot-app'
    version =  '0.1.0'
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.3'
}
```

However, this build script does not work. When running `gradle build`, I get the error `Plugin with id 'spring-boot' not found.` Is this a consequence of trying to use these two syntaxes in conjunction, or am I just doing something silly?

Answer (score 1):

I was being silly. Syntax error on line 6. There shouldn't be a colon after `classpath`.